# Resizing / Aligning Content with Different Screen Sizes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, screen, scale

I'm making an iOS app and for the best part I've been using the iPhone 6 simulator. I have aligned what I have currently at it seems fine on the 6; but when I change the simulator to iPhone 5 for ex. everything overlaps or is out of position.

[This is the iPhone 6 Simulator - Looking Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Fjc.png)

[This is the iPhone 5 Simulator - Looking Awful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJSY2.png)

There have been other tutorials (yes I've looked before you moan) but all I've found are tutorials saying to add new storyboards and assign them to a certain screen size - which seems time consuming and impractical for me (and other people)

Does anyone know an efficient method of getting everything aligned correctly (and scaled down for things like text) for any screen size? Thank you.

Comment: You need Autolayout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: you should go for the universal storyboard not for specific screen sizes and use autolayout constraints so that the constraints should satisfy every screen sizes.. few links for autolayout  https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2                              https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints                                                  https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/ http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-auto-layout-basics--cms-25520

Comment: `stackViews` and `autoLayout` are good options here for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a great tutorial for working with autolayout https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

I seems like you are using constants for you constraints. For example, the width of the UIlables do not change from the iPhone6 to iPhone5. In general, you want to avoid using constants for your constraints and use multiples or ratios instead. For example, instead of having a text field width be 50, have it be 1/3 of the screen width.

A simple fix in your case would be to set the right constraint of your text field equal to the left constraint of your tabs and textfield.